# Insert Data into MySQL DB using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to PHP and MySQL. I am attempting to develop a Student Information System. Below is the code that i am using to insert information from a form to the database but does not seem to be working when I submit the form. Please tell me where i may be going wrong.

The table is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sims`.`tbl_users` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The insert code is as below:

```
//Create new user
    if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_users (name, email, password) VALUES (:name, :email, :password)";
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name',$_POST['name']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password',password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

        if($stmt->execute() ):
            die('Success');
        else:
            die('fail');
        endif;

    endif;
```

Comment: Are you sure you are going into your if statement ? Can you do a var_dump() of one of the $_POST Variable ?

Comment: post the html form for this. You've a typo up there, but that isn't the only thing wrong here.

Comment: You also can't do `password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT)` with `bindParam()`, you'll get an error about it, in regards to "Strict Standards".

Comment: I stuck around this question long enough; take it up with the answers below. Typos, sure. Solution? I doubt it (not my downvotes neither). Good luck.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i found the typo in my if statement

Comment: well, that isn't the only thing wrong here. Your code will fail, that is for sure.

Comment: well after correcting the typo it works...what else would you say is wrong with it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have a typo there in your **if statement**:

```
if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['passowrd']))
                                                                           ^^
```

Comment: Wow!...Don't i feel like an idiot....

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in your condition:
...!empty($_POST['**passowrd**']))...